# How to recover collection that are dropped but in a pending state in the MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, collections, drop, data-recovery, recover

Can anyone help me to restore the collection that is in a pending state after the drop?
I accidentally deleted a collection.

I run

```
db.getCollectionNames({includePendingDrops: true})
```

and I get the list of the collections that are in a pending state. Is there any way to recover them?

Comment: have you tried renaming the collection?

Comment: When a collection is dropped you have several minutes before the data files are reaped.  You can use bsondump to restore them, but you need to be quick about getting copies of these files. See https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/bsondump.1.html

Comment: Do you have no backup?

Comment: No there is no backup